# How do I find the questions I need to accept?

Tags: support, profile-page, accepted-answer

Some questions have complicated answers that I can't test right away.  I know I've forgotten to accept some of them.  I'd like to go through my questions and find the ones that need me to accept answers, where appropriate.

How do I get a list of my unaccepted questions?  I can't find a way to sort by unanswered in my profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case [your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135277/emmby) is all that's needed since you have so few, more generically (for other people finding this later) you can search for your unaccepted questions in the search box using this query: `user:me hasaccepted:0`, here's a direct link to test it out:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+hasaccepted:0

**me** gets replaced with your user ID when searching, or you can use your user ID directly, for example:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:135277+hasaccepted:0

Answer (score 2):

In the search box use:

```
user:me hasaccepted:0
```

See [Search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=) for more!

Answer (score 0):

Though you can't sort, it is directly through your profile. Clicking your name and under the "Questions" portion is your best bet. A little tedious, yes, but not too bad.

Though it may be a good idea from the user's perspective to have a sort by unanswered. Make it as easy as possible to have people fix their acceptance rating.

Comment: Do you mean "sort by accepted/unaccepted" rather than "sort by unanswered"?

Comment: @ChrisF: I suppose semantics does tend to cloud this one. Yes, sort by accepted (and sub-sort by oldest/most proposed answers possibly--those with higher probably to have something to accept). Though I'd be curious to see the ratio of people with pages of questions and those that have low accept ratings (do a lot of users with 3,4,5+ pages also have a lot of questions with no accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Soap box time... if you are asking so many questions that you can't keep track of which ones you have recently asked, and remember what answers you have received, and keep track of which answers you are satisfied with... *you are asking way too many questions*.

**Slow down, cowboy, and focus on one question at a time.**

Comment: Your soapbox is unnecessary and misdirected.